# Save in MongoDB for each element in array using array.map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I am trying to create a document in my mongodb database for each item in my array.

I know it can be done by using `array.forEach()` and pushing an element to an array for every iteration.

But I rather want to achieve the same with `array.map()`.

I have tried

```
const a = 2;
const myArray = [3, 4, 5, 6];
const nodes = myArray.map((b) => {
  const node = new Node({
    a: a,
    b: b
  });
  node.save((err, newNode) => {
    return {
      data: {
        id: newNode.id,
        a: a,
        b: b
      }
    };
  });
});
```

but it returns `[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]`.

I guess it's because it waits for `node.save()` to run.

Also, since I know that I will create multiple documents at once, is it possible to do this instead of calling the database multiple times? I still need the IDs, but I guess I can generate these before hitting the database?

Answer (score 0):

you can insert multiple document with [{multi: true}](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#insert-multiple-documents)

your code does not return anything, but like you said, even if you return node.save(), it might return immediately. you can enforce it with Promise.all

```
const a = 2;
const myArray = [3, 4, 5, 6];
const nodes = myArray.map((b) => {
  const node = new Node({
    a: a,
    b: b
  });
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    node.save((err, newNode) => {
      resolve({
        data: {
          id: newNode.id,
          a: a,
          b: b
        }
      })
    });
  })
});
Promise.all(nodes, (result__ARRAY) => {
   // do something with this array, 
})
```